# Issue with decryption of Weblogic Credentials

Tags: java, encryption, weblogic

I've created a config and key file using this command

```
java weblogic.Admin -username test_user -password test_user -userconfigfile C:\temp\testingconfig.config -userkeyfile C:\temp\testingkey.key STOREUSERCONFIG
```

The config and key are

**weblogic.management.username**=
`{3DES}1VR2QW0Yj3XHj/iEr+z9Mve3mJi0RSCw3J62m1rb063xLAHPTwXcS6X+VRC6tI8xsHriNfYtsB0\=`
**weblogic.management.password**=
`{3DES}ALU/yO2Zi4Z7SkVj1qJDvckmy7Y1DpDc7654xPIeg2zaj5On6yxa6xB0L4Xf0oS0d/9vtLFkgps\=`

When I'm trying to decrypt these credentials using config and key with my java code, I'm getting some other encrypted value:

**Password**=`[C@3ba08dab`

**Username**=`{AES}OLU4ELDpdXulGpd4abYvYbN7i/ngvXbBFZ+/UyYk89I=`

The java code I've written is

```
UsernameAndPassword file = UserConfigFileManager
                    .getUsernameAndPassword(<Path to config file>,
                            <Path to key file>",weblogic.management");
```

So how to get **decrypted** credentials within java code as **test_user/test_user** using config and key.

Kindly help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For resolving the issue, we need to follow these steps:

- Have latest version of weblogic. Newer verseions are working using
  AES security algorithm.
- For receiving the string value of username/password, we can do:

  - `file.getUsername().toString/file.getPassword().toString`
  - `file.getUsername()/file.getPassword()`
  - `new String(file.getUsername())/new String(file.getPassword())`

Out of all the three we've to follow the third one. Doesn't know the exact reason. But creating string object and then fetching value through it gives us the correct result. The exact value we've received in the three cases were.

1. First Case:- Username/password= Some Encrypted Value
2. Second Case:-

   - Username:- Correct Value
   - Password:- null
3. Third Case:

   - Username:- Correct Value
   - Password:- Correct Value

Answer (score 0):

Sample WLST-script:

```
from weblogic.security import UserConfigFileManager

def decrypt(cred_file, secret_key):
  u_and_p = UserConfigFileManager.getUsernameAndPassword(cred_file, secret_key, "weblogic.management")
  return (u_and_p.getUsername(), u_and_p.getPassword().tostring())

config_path = '/path/to/config/file'
key_path = '/path/to/key/file'

print decrypt(config_path, key_path)
```

Sample output:

```
('admin', 'Pa$$w0rd')
```

This code works for a couple years for me without problems.

And an example how to create new pair from WLST:

```
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])))
from weblogic.security import UserConfigFileManager
from weblogic.security import UsernameAndPassword

ADMIN_USERNAME = 'admin'
ADMIN_PASSWORD = 'Pa$$w0rd'
CONFIG_PATH = '/path/to/config/file'
KEY_PATH = '/path/to/key/file'

System.setProperty('weblogic.management.confirmKeyfileCreation', 'true')

u_and_p = UsernameAndPassword(ADMIN_USERNAME, ADMIN_PASSWORD)
UserConfigFileManager.setUsernameAndPassword(u_and_p, CONFIG_PATH, KEY_PATH, 'weblogic.management')
```